# Page not redirecting when a specific controller is used

Tags: apex, visualforce

I want to redirect to a VF page based on some conditions and I have the target page created and saved. However when I am a specific controller (Sobject), the page is not redirecting. I tried with a different standard controller and without controller, page redirected in both cases. I have other functions in the same apex class that redirects to VF page with same standard controller and it works fine. I wonder is there any limit on the number of visualforce pages that an object/controller can reference?

**function in Controller - privateLabelSellSheetCustomizer**

```
public inherited sharing class privateLabelSellSheetCustomizer {
public String savedSellSheetName{get;set;}
public privateLabelSellSheetCustomizer(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        this.pLabel = (Private_Label__c)stdController.getRecord();
    }
}
public Pagereference openSavedSellSheets(){
            savedSellSheetName = apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('inputSellSheetName');
            if(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('inputSellSheetName') == null) 
            {
                ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Error fetching details'));
                return null;
            }
            else{         
                PageReference pageReference = new PageReference('/apex/testNewPage');
                pageReference.setRedirect(false);
                return pageReference;
            }
      }
}
```

**VF Page - source page**

```
<apex:page standardController="Private_Label__c" extensions="privateLabelSellSheetCustomizer" lightningStylesheets="true">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    
        function fireCheckSellSheetName(){
           
        }
        function fireOpenSavedSellSheets(){
            
        }
    
    </script>
<apex:form >
   
    <apex:pageBlock id="main">
        <apex:pageMessages />
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Sell Sheet Information" columns="2" id="sellSheetDetailsSelector">
            <apex:inputText value="{!sellSheetName}" label="Sell Sheet Name" id="sellSheetName" required="false" onblur="fireCheckSellSheetName();"></apex:inputText>
            <apex:inputField id="fireOpenSavedSellSheets" value="{!Private_Label__c.Sell_Sheet_Master__c}" onchange="fireOpenSavedSellSheets();"></apex:inputField>
            <apex:outputText value="{!testSavedSellSheetName}" label="Test:"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Sell Sheet Templates" columns="2">
         
                <input type="radio" style="margin-left:150px;" id="template1" onclick="checkRadio();"/>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <img src = "" width="300px" height="400px"/>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                
                    <apex:inputText value="{!sellSheetTitle}" label="Sell Sheet Title" id="txtSellSheetTitle" required="false"  ></apex:inputText>
           
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom" >
            <apex:commandButton value="Next - Select Products >" action="{!goToSecondPage}" />
            
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:actionFunction name="fireCheckSellSheetName" action="{!checkSellSheetName}" reRender="main">
    
    </apex:actionFunction>
    <apex:actionFunction name="fireOpenSavedSellSheets" action="{!openSavedSellSheets}" reRender="main">
        <apex:param name="inputSellSheetName" value="" />
    </apex:actionFunction>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**VF - targetpage**

```
<apex:page standardController="Private_Label__c" extensions="privateLabelSellSheetCustomizer"   lightningStylesheets="true">

</apex:page>
```

Comment: Your page doesn't contain any interaction elements. How are you expecting `openSavedSellSheets()` to be executed?

Comment: @David I have actionFunction in the VF page which calls this function. function call is working as I tested it with other pages using a different controller other than 'Private_Label__c'. the problem occurs only when redirecting to a page with this standard controller

Comment: @DavidReed The vf page above shown is the target page

Comment: Please [edit] to provide a complete example that can reproduce your problem.

Comment: @DavidReed updated. Please check

Comment: you have a JS function AND an actionFunction with the same name: `fireOpenSavedSellSheets`